# Replacing an xml element value in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-entities, xmldocument

Here is my xml file data

```
<Persons>
    <Person>
        <Name>john</Name>
    </Person>
    <Employee>
        <Detail>
            <Firstname>john</FirstName>
        </Detail>
    </Employee>
    <Student>
        <FullName>john</FullName>
    </Student>
</Persons>
```

I want to replace "john" to "danny" in all places.

How can I do this in c# ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possible way using [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("path_to_xml_file.xml");

//select all leaf elements having value equals "john"
var elementsToUpdate = doc.Descendants()
                          .Where(o => o.Value == "john" && !o.HasElements);

//update elements value
foreach(XElement element in elementsToUpdate)
{
    element.Value = "danny";
}

//save the XML back as file
doc.Save("path_to_xml_file.xml");
```

Notice that `XElement.Value` contains *all text nodes* within the element, *concatenated*.

The significance of this is, for example, considering your XML as input, not only `<Name>` has value of "john" but also `<Person>`. But we only want to update the leaf elements not the ancestors.

<sub>*) I assumed you didn't really meant to tag the question by [xmldocument](/questions/tagged/xmldocument) so this answer using the newer XML API `XDocument`, though using XmlDocument is also possible.</sub>